# How to lock android tablet for web browsing only?

Tags: applications, security, kiosk-mode

Im developing a web app for some clients and Im going to lend then an android tablet (one of those cheap chinese non-brand tablets, pretty easy to manipulate) and Im kind of new into android so I want to know how can I lock all system apps (including settings) and leave them with google chrome enabled, even with a browsing lock that only allows to navigate in the desired domain.

As a plus I would like to have like a remote monitoring of the tablet so I can see the activity.

Im asking such an ambiguous way cause I dont know anything about android, but I imagine that this can be done because is such an open OS. If someone can recommend me some apps or website where I can get more info about this.

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of Android u Use? are you a Android developer. If you are going to lend the Tablet to the customer for a short time(Such as a small demo) you can  use "Screen Pinning" option in android.

Comment: @Avinash Remember that screen pinning doesn't resume itself if the app it allows access to crashes or is closed via e.g. tapping an "Exit" button inside it.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Yes. It is not a permenant solution. but for a short demo it is OK

Comment: @Avinash It is, *unless the user manages to crash Chrome*.

Comment: Please look at the questions under [tag:kiosk-mode].

Comment: Since you are looking at additional features which are beyond what has been pointed out by Fire lord, see single use set up https://developer.android.com/work/cosu

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is probably to use Google's [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/), it's compatible with all Android devices running Android 5.1 or above.

To lock the device on one app, or on multiple app, you define a kiosk policy like below:

```
"applications": [
 {
   "packageName": "com.example.app",
   "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
   "lockTaskAllowed": true,
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
 },
 {
   "packageName": "com.example.app2",
   "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
   "lockTaskAllowed": true,
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
 }
"persistentPreferredActivities": [
  {
    "receiverActivity": "com.example.app/.com.example.app.MainActivity",
    "actions": [
      "android.intent.action.MAIN"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "android.intent.category.HOME",
      "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```